# How to access data in a re.findinter output object?

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to access the 'span' and 'match' data from the object I've generated with regex.findinter.  But I can't find how to transfer the object structure into a pandas df so I can manipulate it more easily.

I can iterate through the object to print the data. But the regex.findinter documentation does not say how to access the data.  The best I can find is the page https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/match-objects.html

I tried just appending the rows to a pandas df but no luck.  See code.  It gives error:
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

```
import re
import pandas as pd


def find_rez(string):
    regex = re.compile(r'\s\d{10}\s')
    return(regex.finditer(string))

#open file with text data
file = open('prepaid_transactions_test2.txt')
text = file.read()

#get regex object with locations of all matches.
rez_mo = find_rez(text)

#Create empty df with span and match columns.
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['span','match'])

#Append each row from object to pandas df. NOT WORKING.
for i in rez_mo:
    df.append(i)
```

I'd like to have a pandas df with the range & match as columns. But I'm failing at converting the types it seems.

Comment: Using the `read_csv()` method on the text file then making the relevent filters on the dataframe using a regex with pandas `loc` might be an easier way forward

Comment: Thanks, but the source data is in an unstructured txt fomat (from OCR).  I'm extracting and formatting specific data from that.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution.  May not be most elegant but....it works.

```
for i in rez_mo:
    df.loc[len(df)]=[i.start()],[i.group()]
```